# Rider shows a warning that a variable can be null even if an attribute is present that it is not null

Tags: c#, attributes, nullable, rider, notnull

I created a regular `TryGet` method, but added the `NotNullWhen(true)` attribute to its `out` parameter, which means that the variable cannot be null if the method returns `true`. When using the method further, Rider writes a warning that the variable can be null, despite the fact that the method returns true. Why is this happening? Is there a way to get rid of the warning without ignoring it?

```
private bool TryGet(bool flag, [NotNullWhen(true)]out string? str)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            str = "568";
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            str = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    private int Test()
    {
        var test = TryGet(true, out var str);
        var test2 = test ? int.Parse(str) : 0; //For "str": possible null reference argument
        return test2;
    }
```